# How to Make Sense of Dagger Hilt Build Output - Migrating from Dagger 2 to Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, migration, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

Migrating app from Dagger 2 to Hilt (I'm pretty new to this).  I may have bitten off more than I can chew.  I have been troubleshooting this for days now and I'm not exactly sure how to read the build output.  Can someone help makes sense of what these error messages mean?

Is there a resource for decoding these errors?

```
> Task :companyname:kaptDebugKotlin
/Users/pete/companyname/droid/appname/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/companyname/db/dependencyinjection/AppComponent.java:34: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] @dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface AppComponent {
                ^
      @dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext android.content.Context is injected at
          com.appname.db.dependencyinjection.AppModule.provideContext$appname_debug(application)
      android.content.Context is injected at
          com.appname.db.network.NetworkService.providesHarInterceptor(context)
      com.appname.db.network.HarInterceptor is injected at
          com.appname.db.network.NetworkService.providesNetworkService(…, harInterceptor)
      com.appname.db.network.NetworkService is requested at
          com.appname.db.dependencyinjection.AppComponent.providesNetworkService()
  It is also requested at:
      com.appname.db.dependencyinjection.AppModule.provideApplication(application)
  The following other entry points also depend on it:
      com.appname.db.dependencyinjection.AppComponent.inject(com.appname.BaseApplication)
      com.appname.db.dependencyinjection.AppComponent.inject(com.appname.contacts.vm.ContactDetailViewModel)
/Users/pete/companyname/droid/appname/src/main/java/com/appname/fragments/BaseApiDialogFragment.java:24: error: [Hilt]
public abstract class BaseApiDialogFragment<T extends Parcelable> extends BaseDialogFragment
                ^
  @AndroidEntryPoint-annotated classes cannot have type parameters.
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
/Users/pete/companyname/droid/appname/src/main/java/com/appname/fragments/BaseApiDialogFragment.java:24: error: [Hilt]
public abstract class BaseApiDialogFragment<T extends Parcelable> extends BaseDialogFragment
                ^
  @AndroidEntryPoint-annotated classes cannot have type parameters.
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
/Users/pete/companyname/droid/appname/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/appname/ui/epoxy/ComponentSectionHeaderModel.java:23: error: [Hilt]
public abstract class ComponentSectionHeaderModel extends com.airbnb.epoxy.DataBindingEpoxyModel {
                ^
  @AndroidEntryPoint base class must extend ComponentActivity, (support) Fragment, View, Service, or BroadcastReceiver.
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
/Users/pete/companyname/droid/appname/src/main/java/com/appname/fragments/BaseApiDialogFragment.java:24: error: [Hilt]
public abstract class BaseApiDialogFragment<T extends Parcelable> extends BaseDialogFragment
                ^
  @AndroidEntryPoint-annotated classes cannot have type parameters.
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
/Users/pete/companyname/droid/appname/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/appname/contacts/network/ContactsDataSourceFactory.java:20: error: [Hilt]
public final class ContactsDataSourceFactory {
             ^
  @AndroidEntryPoint base class must extend ComponentActivity, (support) Fragment, View, Service, or BroadcastReceiver.
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
/Users/pete/companyname/droid/appname/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/appname/contacts/epoxy/ComponentChatMessageModel.java:23: error: [Hilt]
public abstract class ComponentChatMessageModel extends com.airbnb.epoxy.DataBindingEpoxyModel {
                ^
  @AndroidEntryPoint base class must extend ComponentActivity, (support) Fragment, View, Service, or BroadcastReceiver.
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
/Users/pete/companyname/droid/appname/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/appname/http/BaseHttpService.java:36: error: [Hilt]
public class BaseHttpService {
       ^
  @AndroidEntryPoint base class must extend ComponentActivity, (support) Fragment, View, Service, or BroadcastReceiver.
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
/Users/pete/companyname/droid/appname/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/appname/http/BaseWebService.java:31: error: [Hilt]
public abstract class BaseWebService<ParamType extends java.lang.Object, RawDataType extends java.lang.Object, ProgressType extends java.lang.Object, ResultType extends java.lang.Object> extends android.os.AsyncTask<ParamType, ProgressType, ResultType> {
                ^
  @AndroidEntryPoint-annotated classes cannot have type parameters.
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
/Users/pete/companyname/droid/appname/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/appname/http/BaseWebService.java:305: error: [Hilt]
    public static final class ClientWrapper {
                        ^
  @AndroidEntryPoint base class must extend ComponentActivity, (support) Fragment, View, Service, or BroadcastReceiver.
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
/Users/pete/companyname/droid/appname/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/appname/commute/CommuteTimeManager.java:25: error: [Hilt]
public final class CommuteTimeManager implements com.appname.commute.CommuteTimeListener {
             ^
  @AndroidEntryPoint base class must extend ComponentActivity, (support) Fragment, View, Service, or BroadcastReceiver.
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
/Users/pete/companyname/droid/appname/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/appname/workers/VerifyLoginWorker.java:16: error: [Hilt]
public class VerifyLoginWorker extends androidx.work.CoroutineWorker {
       ^
  @AndroidEntryPoint base class must extend ComponentActivity, (support) Fragment, View, Service, or BroadcastReceiver.
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
warning: Binding adapter AK(android.widget.ImageView, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) already exists for android:src! Overriding androidx.databinding.adapters.ImageViewBindingAdapter#setImageDrawable with com.appname.ui.DataBindingAdapters#setImageDrawable
Binding adapter AK(android.widget.ImageView, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) already exists for android:src! Overriding androidx.databinding.adapters.ImageViewBindingAdapter#setImageDrawable with com.appname.ui.DataBindingAdapters#setImageDrawable


> Task :appname:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

Execution failed for task ':appname:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':appname:kaptDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:187)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:268)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:408)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:395)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:388)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:374)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:342)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:142)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForAll(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:506)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:483)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:466)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:105)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:270)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:83)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:60)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:105)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:86)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:86)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution$2.withWorkspace(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:283)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:408)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:395)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:388)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:374)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution.run(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:288)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction.execute(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:243)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:206)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:214)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.util.KaptBaseError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:132)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:31)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:45)
    ... 31 more
```

***Post Limited to 30000 characters See AppComponent in Comments: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72914403/11489088)***

Comment: Could you include the AppComponent interface? and other di related classes?

Comment: I put the AppComponent in another answer since posts are limited to 30,000 characters.  There are a lot of related classes.  I annotated the `MapActivity` and the fragments with @AndroidEntryPoint.  View Models with @HiltViewModel, then @Inject constructor with the params.  The BaseApplication has @HiltAndroidApp.  If there are specific ones I could post that would be more helpful lmk.

Comment: Update: I added the modules to the additional comment if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ditch the `AppComponent` and just inject whatever you need directly to Fragments and Activities.

As for your `AppModule`, you don't really need to provide the application context via `provideContext`-- if something needs an Application Context, then you just pass context in the constructor and annotate it with `@ApplicationContext`, something like this:

```
@Singleton
class SomeObject @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext private val context: Context) {
//...
```

Also when you do this, you'll never need to have a separate `providesSomeObject` function in a module. It's understood that this object can be injected to whoever needs it (this is indicated by the `@Inject` annotation)

You could actually do something similar for your functions in `AnalyticsModule`--ditch using `@Inject` on them as well:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AnalyticsModule {

// ...

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Inject
    fun providesFirebaseAnalytics(@ApplicationContext context: Context): FirebaseAnalytics =
        FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context)

}
```

Your `NetworkService` class looks weird, it looks like it doubles as a Hilt module and then you allow it to be injected to other classes--I wouldn't do that and instead just have classes inject the Retrofit APIs to their constructors.

As for your other errors (`@AndroidEntryPoint-annotated classes cannot have type parameters`), I know you can inject objects to Abstract/Base classes, but the base class itself should not have any `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotations--instead the annotation should be in classes that extend from the base class.

You can probably do away with other custom components in your app have and put all your modules in `SingletonComponent`, see this [link](https://dagger.dev/hilt/components.html) for more info on components. Activities and Fragments need to be annotated as entry points as mentioned before.

Comment: Thanks! I've been working through some of these issues based on your suggestions throughout the day. This is a large application with a lot of moving parts, so I'm still getting error messages.  To go back to my original question, was there something in the errors that pointed you to this? I've been pouring over docs for a week and am still confused when it won't compile.  I'm not really sure how to troubleshoot these error messages.  I keep just trying something, then clean and run.  Try something, then clean and run.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Nope it doesn't have to be that way. Have you read https://dagger.dev/hilt/migration-guide.html? It really helped me when I migrated to Hilt. Are you still getting the same errors?

Comment: I have followed it and read through it many times at this point, yes. I am getting similar errors.

Comment: What I've done so far: Added @\HiltAndroidApp to the BaseApplication class, added @\AndroidEntryPoint to every injection that used to be in the AppComponent (MapActivity, ContactsDataSourceFactory, ContactDetailFragment, ContactDetailCreateFragment, BaseHttpService, BaseWebService.ClientWrapper, PDFViewerFragment, CommuteTimeManager, VerifyLoginWorker, LoginWebFragment), AppComponent removed, added @\HiltViewModel to the view models that had an inject function in the AppComponent (NetworkBaseViewModel, ContactDetailViewModel, ContactsListViewModel, ActivityFeedViewModel), ...

Comment: Added @\inject with a constructor into the HiltViewModels, removed all gradle dependencies that had dagger.android, added @\ApplicationContext to any instance that was calling the provideApplicationContext function from the AppModule, annotated the AnalyticsModule with @\InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)

Comment: I have also removed all instances of AggregatorEntryPoint since it looks like I am way past the need for it if all of the other dagger dependencies are removed.

Comment: Still receiving error: "error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] @\dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext com.companyname.BaseApplication cannot be provided without an @\Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements BaseApplication_GeneratedInjector,"

Still not sure what this is showing me.  Does this mean that these are the places that are being injected and I need to fix the places that are not listed, or vice versa?

Comment: Hi @petestmart, you have a dependency somewhere that needs `BaseApplication`, it's probably the `providesSegmentAnalytics` and `providesFirebaseAnalytics` functions in your `AnalyticsModule`. Do they really need `BaseApplication` injected or do you just need its context? For `providesSegmentAnalytics`, if you only need it for release builds, consider having a separate implementation of  class under the release `src` folder

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to put a bow on this conversation, is the build output showing me where the instances have been injected, and then I troubleshoot this by looking for spots that *should be* injected but are not injected?

Comment: Hi @petestmart, not exactly, for the `BaseApplication` error, the error tells you that `BaseApplication` needs to be injected somewhere due to a class declaring it needs a `BaseApplication` via `@Inject`, and you haven't specified how to create a `BaseApplication`.  It really depends on the output, for your original post for example, the error for `ClientWrapper` says that it isn't a valid class where you can put in the `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation

Answer (score 0):

Since posts are limited to 30,000 characters I will post the AppComponent and Modules here.

App Component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class, NetworkService::class, AnalyticsModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    fun providesNetworkService(): NetworkService

    fun inject(activity: MapActivity)
    fun inject(viewModel: NetworkBaseViewModel)
    fun inject(application: BaseApplication)
    fun inject(contactsDataSourceFactory: ContactsDataSourceFactory)
    fun inject(contactDetailViewModel: ContactDetailViewModel)
    fun inject(contactDetailFragment: ContactDetailFragment)
    fun inject(contactDetailEditFragment: ContactDetailEditFragment)
    fun inject(contactDetailCreateFragment: ContactDetailCreateFragment)
    fun inject(contactsListViewModel: ContactsListViewModel)
    fun inject(activityFeedViewModel: ActivityFeedViewModel)
    fun inject(httpService: BaseHttpService)
    fun inject(httpService: BaseWebService.ClientWrapper)
    fun inject(pdfViewerFragment: PDFViewerFragment)
    fun inject(commuteTimeManager: CommuteTimeManager)
    fun inject(verifyLoginWorker: VerifyLoginWorker)
    fun inject(loginWebFragment: LoginWebFragment)
}
```

AppModule:

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class AppModule constructor () {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplication(@ApplicationContext application: Context): BaseApplication {
    return application as BaseApplication
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideContext(@ApplicationContext application: Context): Context = application
}
```

NetworkService:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class NetworkService {

    object Keys {
        const val GRAPH_QL_OKHTTP_CLIENT = "graph_ql"
        const val ACTIVITY_FEED_RETROFIT = "activity_feed_retrofit"
        const val ACTIVITY_FEED_OKHTTP = "activity_feed_client"
    }

    private val baseUrl: String = BaseApplication.baseUrl
    private val feedBaseUrl: String = BaseApplication.feedBaseUrl

    lateinit var api: NetworkServiceAPI
    lateinit var feedApi: FeedNetworkServiceAPI
    lateinit var harInterceptor: HarInterceptor

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideAPI(retrofit: Retrofit): NetworkServiceAPI {
        return retrofit.create(NetworkServiceAPI::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideFeedAPI(@Named(Keys.ACTIVITY_FEED_RETROFIT) retrofit: Retrofit): FeedNetworkServiceAPI {
        return retrofit.create(FeedNetworkServiceAPI::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideRetrofit(gson: Gson, okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        val contentType = "application/json".toMediaType()
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(defaultJson.asConverterFactory(contentType))
//                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named(Keys.ACTIVITY_FEED_RETROFIT)
    internal fun provideFeedRetrofit(@Named(Keys.ACTIVITY_FEED_OKHTTP) okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        val contentType = "application/json".toMediaType()
        val converter = defaultJson.asConverterFactory(contentType)
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(feedBaseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(converter)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Inject
    internal fun provideClient(chuckerInterceptor: ChuckerInterceptor,
    harInterceptor: HarInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addCertificateTransparencyInterceptor()

        builder.addInterceptor(object : Interceptor {
            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                val url = chain.request().url.toString()
                Timber.d("Calling HomeSpotter URL: $url")
                val requestBuilder = chain.request().newBuilder()

                // Add every default header to all connections that are made
                val headers = Brand.getInstance().getHttpHeaders(url)
                for ((key, value) in headers) {
                    requestBuilder.addHeaderRemovingSymbols(key, value)
                }

                return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build())
            }
        })
                .addNetworkLoggingInterceptor(chuckerInterceptor)
                .addInterceptor(harInterceptor)

        if (DEBUGGABLE) {
            // In Debug, log network requests
            val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC
            builder.addInterceptor(logging)
                    .addInterceptor(CurlInterceptor { message -> Timber.d(message) })
        }

        return builder.build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Inject
    @Named(Keys.ACTIVITY_FEED_OKHTTP)
    internal fun provideActivityFeedClient(
            chuckerInterceptor: ChuckerInterceptor,
            harInterceptor: HarInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addCertificateTransparencyInterceptor()

        builder.addInterceptor(object : Interceptor {
            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                val url = chain.request().url.toString()
                Timber.d("Calling HomeSpotter URL: $url")
                val requestBuilder = chain.request().newBuilder()

                // Add every default header to all connections that are made
                val headers = Brand.getInstance().getHttpHeaders(url)
                val apiToken = BaseApplication.sharedPrefs.getString(AppConstants.API_TOKEN, null)
                apiToken?.let { headers["Api-key"] = it }
                headers.forEach { (key, value) ->
                    requestBuilder.addHeaderRemovingSymbols(key, value)
                }

                return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build())
            }
        })
                .addNetworkLoggingInterceptor(chuckerInterceptor)
                .addNetworkInterceptor(harInterceptor)

        if (DEBUGGABLE) {
            // In Debug, log network requests
            val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC
            builder.addInterceptor(logging)
                    .addInterceptor(CurlInterceptor { message -> Timber.d(message) })
        }

        return builder.build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Inject
    @Named(Keys.GRAPH_QL_OKHTTP_CLIENT)
    internal fun provideGraphQlClient(
            chuckerInterceptor: ChuckerInterceptor,
            harInterceptor: HarInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addCertificateTransparencyInterceptor()

        builder.addInterceptor(object : Interceptor {
            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                val url = chain.request().url.toString()
                Timber.d("Calling HomeSpotter URL: $url")
                val requestBuilder = chain.request().newBuilder()

                // Add every default header to all connections that are made
                val headers = Brand.getInstance().getHttpHeaders(url)
                val useSuperToken = false
                val superUserToken = BaseApplication.appResources.getString(R.string.activity_feed_super_user_token)
                val apiToken = if (useSuperToken && DEBUGGABLE && superUserToken.isNotEmpty()) {
                    superUserToken
                } else {
                    BaseApplication.sharedPrefs.getString(AppConstants.API_TOKEN, null)
                }
                if (apiToken != null) headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $apiToken"
                headers.forEach { (key, value) ->
                    requestBuilder.addHeaderRemovingSymbols(key, value)
                }

                return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build())
            }
        })

                .addNetworkLoggingInterceptor(chuckerInterceptor)
                .addNetworkInterceptor(harInterceptor)

        if (DEBUGGABLE) {
            // In Debug, log network requests
            val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC
            builder.addInterceptor(logging)
                    .addInterceptor(CurlInterceptor { message -> Timber.d(message) })
        }

        return builder.build()
    }

    private fun OkHttpClient.Builder.addCertificateTransparencyInterceptor(): OkHttpClient.Builder = apply {
        addNetworkInterceptor(certificateTransparencyInterceptor())
    }

    private fun OkHttpClient.Builder.addNetworkLoggingInterceptor(interceptor: ChuckerInterceptor): OkHttpClient.Builder = apply {
        if (BaseApplication.sharedPrefs.getBoolean(AppConstants.DEBUG_ENABLE_NETWORK_LOGGING, false)) {
            addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor)
        }
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Inject
    fun providesNetworkLoggingInterceptor(context: Context): ChuckerInterceptor {
        return ChuckerInterceptor(context)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Inject
    fun providesHarInterceptor(context: Context): HarInterceptor {
        return HarInterceptor(context)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Inject
    fun providesApolloClient(@Named(Keys.GRAPH_QL_OKHTTP_CLIENT) okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): ApolloClient {
        val apiUrl: String = BaseApplication.apiBaseUrl
        return ApolloClient.builder().serverUrl("$apiUrl/graphql")
                .okHttpClient(okHttpClient).build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideGson(): Gson {
        return GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .serializeNulls()
                .create()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Inject
    fun providesNetworkService(api: NetworkServiceAPI,
                               feedApi: FeedNetworkServiceAPI,
                                harInterceptor: HarInterceptor): NetworkService {
        this.api = api
        this.feedApi = feedApi
        this.harInterceptor = harInterceptor
        return this
    }

    companion object {
        val defaultJson = Json {
            encodeDefaults = true
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
            isLenient = true
            allowSpecialFloatingPointValues = false
        }
    }

}

fun Request.Builder.addHeaderRemovingSymbols(key: String, value: String?): Request.Builder {
    Timber.d("Header: $key : $value")
    value?.let { return addHeader(key, it.replace(Regex("[^\\u0020-\\u007e‘’]"), "")) }
    return this
}
```

Analytics Module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AnalyticsModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Inject
    fun providesHsAnalytics(firebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics?, segmentAnalytics: Analytics?): HsAnalytics {
        return HsAnalytics(firebaseAnalytics, segmentAnalytics)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Inject
    fun providesSegmentAnalytics(application: BaseApplication): Analytics? {
        val segmentKey = application.getString(if (BaseApplication.isReleaseBuild) R.string.segment_release_key else R.string.segment_dev_key)
        if (segmentKey.isNotEmpty()) {
            return Analytics.Builder(application, segmentKey)
                    .trackApplicationLifecycleEvents()
                    .build()
                    .apply { updateIdentity(application) }
        }
        Timber.d("Segment analytics not set-up: Key: $segmentKey")
        return null
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Inject
    fun providesFirebaseAnalytics(application: BaseApplication): FirebaseAnalytics? {
        return try {
            FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(application)
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            Timber.e(e)
            null
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the intention for `interface AppComponent`? Is it for injecting dependencies to Activities and Fragments?

Comment: @AlvinDizon Correct. This is the AppComponent that was set up for dagger by another developer. It appears to inject dependencies to Activities, Fragments, etc.

Comment: then you don't need it. You can just do field injection in Activities and Fragments directly (assuming you've annotated them as entry points)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class, NetworkService::class, AnalyticsModule::class])
interface AppComponent {
   fun providesNetworkService(): NetworkService
   [...]
```

To:

```
@Module(includes = [AppModule::class, AnalyticsModule::class])
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class AppComponent {

   @Binds
   abstract fun bindsNetworkService(): NetworkService
   [...]
```

And change your NetworkService from:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class NetworkService {
```

To:

```
class NetworkService @Inject constructor(){
```

Comment: A couple of things: 1) I will give it a try. My code has changed slightly since first posting this.  2) How did you determine these changes based on what you're seeing?